# How to change cell text color with out hiding the separator?

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my my application I want to change the cell text color with out disappearing the cell separator.And I am using the following code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    static NSString *identifier = @"cell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];

        UIView * selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
        [selectedBackgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; // set color here
        [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:selectedBackgroundView];

        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [cell setOpaque:NO];

    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[contentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

But when I clicked the cell the cell separator also is disappearing ? How to change the text color without hiding the separator ?

Comment: Sorry but your question is not clear I mean how and when you want to change your text color?

Comment: @Retro I want to change the text color when clicking the cell

Comment: Set `tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;`
add custom line in Cell

Comment: Make sure that your selectedBackGround View may hide your separator..just comment out this line and try [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:selectedBackgroundView];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the cell separators are a problem for a lot of people. So, I would say rather than doing what I suggested to disable the selection, it would be easier to set the cell separator to 'none' and manage the separator yourself in the background and selected background views:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // ...

    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    static NSString *identifier = @"cell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];

        UIView *selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
        [selectedBackgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:selectedBackgroundView];

        UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
        [backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [cell setBackgroundView:backgroundView];

        UIView *selectedBackgroundSeparator = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(tableView.separatorInset.left, cell.frame.size.height - 1, cell.frame.size.width - tableView.separatorInset.left, 1)];
        UIView *backgroundSeparator = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:selectedBackgroundSeparator.frame];

        selectedBackgroundSeparator.backgroundColor = backgroundSeparator.backgroundColor = tableView.separatorColor;

        [selectedBackgroundView addSubview:selectedBackgroundSeparator];
        [backgroundView addSubview:backgroundSeparator];

        cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [cell setOpaque:NO];

    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[contentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can use the default cell separator, and instead just add your own top and bottom separators to the `selectedBackgroundView`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    static NSString *identifier = @"cell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];

        UIView *selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
        [selectedBackgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:selectedBackgroundView];

        UIView *topSelectedBackgroundSeparator = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(tableView.separatorInset.left, 0, cell.frame.size.width - tableView.separatorInset.left, 1)];
        UIView *selectedBackgroundSeparator = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectOffset(topSelectedBackgroundSeparator.frame, 0, cell.frame.size.height)];

        topSelectedBackgroundSeparator.backgroundColor = selectedBackgroundSeparator.backgroundColor = tableView.separatorColor;

        [selectedBackgroundView addSubview:selectedBackgroundSeparator];
        [selectedBackgroundView addSubview:topSelectedBackgroundSeparator];

        cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [cell setOpaque:NO];

    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[contentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   for(id view in cell.containtView.subview) {
     if([view isKindaOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        UILabel* titleLabel = (UILabel*)view;
        [titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; // any you want
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting the cell's `selectedBackgroundView` to a clear view, would simply not allowing the cell to be highlighted when selected accomplish what you want? It will prevent the cell and separators from changing automatically based on the selection, but you will have to manage recognizing the tap gesture and highlighting the label text yourself.

Remove the `selectedBackgroundView` from your code.

You then need to implement `tableView:shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:` in your `UITableViewDelegate`:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return NO; // do what's appropriate based on the indexPath
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.But when I use the above code,the highlighted text color is not showing ?